# C program terminates when doing fwrite

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, buffer

So in this code what im trying to do is read the initial 44 bytes from a wave file put to a new file then calculate combination by using a sequence of left-right shorts

new file : (intial 44bytes - combination - combination - combination...) but it stops when I try to call fwrite.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * firstFile;
    FILE * finalFile;
    size_t size;
    char *buffer;
    short left;
    short right;
    short combination;
    int loop;

    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    if ((firstFile = fopen("test.wav", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("File error");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(firstFile, 0, SEEK_END);

    size = ftell(firstFile);

    fseek(firstFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    buffer = malloc(44);
    fread(buffer, 1, 44, firstFile);

    finalFile = fopen("new.wav", "rb");
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, finalFile);
    loop = 1;

    while (loop == 1) {
        fread(&left, sizeof(short), 1, firstFile);
        if (fread(&right, sizeof(short), 1, firstFile) == 0) {
            loop = 0;
        }

        combination = (left - right) / 2;
        fwrite(&combination, sizeof(short), 1, finalFile);
    }

    fclose(firstFile);
    fclose(finalFile);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: before accessing anything beyond argv[0], the argc needs to be checked to assure such parameter (as would be in argv[1]) actually exists.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to test the failure of [`fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) like:

```
finalFile = fopen("new.wav", "wb");
if (!finalFile) { perror("new.wav"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

<sup>And if you write a file, open it in write mode.</sup>

You should of course compile with all warnings & debug info:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -o yourbinary
```

and use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: Opening the file in rb mode to write?

Comment: you are my savior. i cant believe i waste 12 hours to find out that i opened the file using rb not wb. im literrally crying right now here is my webcam image http://i.imgur.com/JdQUNO8.png.

Comment: @michael: That's why **one shall always test** the outcome of (system) calls which's result(s) will be used by the following code. Never skip a man-page's "***RETURN VALUE***" and "***ERRORS***" section.

Answer (score 3):

You just opened write file in "rb" mode.

```
finalFile = fopen("new.wav", "rb");
```

Please try

```
finalFile = fopen("new.wav", "wb");
```

and check

```
finalFile==NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Please open file in Write mode , Like "wb"

```
finalFile = fopen("new.wav", "wb");
```

then you have to check the return values

Comment: your answer is just similar to other answers... Please try to answer un answered questions. Or sent different answer.

Answer (score 1):

You opened file in read mode. That's why this issue happened, per the [man page of fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). Please try write mode.